# Move and Rename file using Java

Tags: java

i want to move and rename a file using Java.
I tried this code but it fails to rename:
Any Help please, Thank you

```
public class MoveAndRenameFile {

public MoveAndRenameFile(){
    //Current Date and Time  
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    {
        File file = new File("C:\\FolderA\\Client.pdf");
        File newFile = new File(("C:\\FolderB\\Clientx.pdf"));
        if(file.renameTo(newFile)+dateFormat.format(date)){
            System.out.println("File rename success");;
        }else{
            System.out.println("File rename failed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: how should jvm determine what is the order it should evaluate if you give something like this file.renameTo(newFile)+dateFormat.format(date).

Comment: Consider using Files.move instead of File.renameTo http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: Also it looks like you have a misplaced closing parenthesis.

Comment: The solution is :File newFile = new File(("C:\\FolderB\\Clientx"+System.currentTimeMillis() +".pdf"));

Answer (score 10):

The File I/O API was changed and improved considerably with Java 7. 
One of the [problems with the legacy (pre Java 7) File API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html#interop) was that:

> • The rename method didn't work consistently across platforms

The [NIO.2 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) (File API introduced with Java 7) way of renaming files is using [`Files.move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-):

```
Files.move(file, newFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

The section *Mapping java.io.File Functionality to java.nio.file* in [Legacy File I/O Code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html#interop) will help you to replace your old file operations with new ones.